# Which Drupal cascading menu module support multi-languages?

Tags: drupal, internationalization, menu

Is there a cascading module (e.g. [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus)) supports a multi-language site? i.e. depends on the current language (`example.com/en` > `example.com/de`) the menu can be translated properly (from English to German for the example). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multilangual menus, you first need http://drupal.org/project/i18n.

You can then either have a menu per language or a single menu with a menu entry per language.

Modules like Nice Menu then just format whatever is in your menu anyway in a different way, they don't care if it's multilangual or not.